# how are passwords encoded in pg_shadow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, password, hashing

How are passwords encoded in column `passwd` of pg_shadow?

Doing a:

```
select passwd from pg_shadow;
```

I see values like the following:

```
 md52c92c858aa1fa12144f1dcbd4ca9c3a0
```

... which, doesn't seem to be what I know my password's MD5 hash to be (stripping the leading "md5" obviously). Are the hashes also salted?

Comment: They are salted and hashed twice. There is a plan for BCrypt in future. You can restrict access for non admin users anyway.

Comment: @MladenUzelac it just seems weird (given the salting) that the same password resulted in the same salted hash in two different 9.1 installations (one in Ubuntu the other in a Red Hat system). I guess the salts are the same?

Comment: wrong answer, i put the correct in the comment

Comment: MD5 has been considered insecure for 25 years, since 1996. The fact that PostgreSQL still uses MD5 for hashing passwords reduces my confidence in the whole project. Why is it that one of the best open-source database engines is still using MD5 for the main database passwords, when every random developer knows to use a stronger hash function like bcrypt? How can I trust any aspect of PostgreSQL security if they hash passwords like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually suffixes the password with the username and then MD5 hash is made out of that, and that hash is then prefixed with 'md5'

Comment: For the explanation straight from the horse's mouth, see the description of pg_authid.rolpassword here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-authid.html